# Large OR Expression in Castle.ActiveRecord

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

I am triyng to a do psuedo-fuzzy logic query in active record.

How do I express:

> field1 like 'A' or field2 like 'A' or
>   field3 like 'A' or field1 like 'B' or
>   field2 like 'B' or field3 like 'B'

using the ICriteria objects...where the 'likes' need to be InsensitiveLikeExpressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
    public T[] FuzzyFind<T>(string[] fields, string[] values) where T: class {
        var dis = new Disjunction();
        foreach (var f in fields)
            foreach (var v in values)
                dis.Add(new InsensitiveLikeExpression(f, v, MatchMode.Anywhere));
        return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.FindAll(dis);
    }
```

Then you call it like this:

```
var locations = FuzzyFind<ARAddressableLocation>(new[] { "field1", "field2", "field3 }, new[] { "a", "b" });
```

which produces all combinations of (field, value)

Adjust MatchMode as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its not ICriteria objects, but in HQL the answer is this:

> ```
> string hql = "FROM ARAddressableLocation as al WHERE (LOWER(al.SubNumber) = '{0}' OR LOWER(al.Number) = '{0}' OR...";
> ARAddressableLocation[] obj = (ARAddressableLocation[])Execute(
>     delegate(ISession session, object instance) {
>       IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
>       IList results = query.List();
>
>       ARAddressableLocation[] list = new ARAddressableLocation[results.Count];
>       results.CopyTo(list, 0);
>
>       return list;
>     }, null);
> ```

My fields are all always strings, so I elected to put them in myself instead of using NHibernate's parameters.

(votes up for the answer would be appreciated)

Comment: Does "WHERE AND >" work? Plus, not using proper parameters can be dangerous: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/30/ORMAndSQLInjections.aspx

Comment: Opps that was a typo sorry.  I will fix it.